# How can you store data in such a way that they are not lost after deleting then installing the the ios?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite, core-data

Can core data do the job or should I use sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, applications on iOS run in a sandboxed environment. That means, you can only manipulate with things in your sandbox. However, when app is removed, so is the sandbox. Even if you install the application again, it will be completely clean. The only storage which is persisted across multiple installations of the app is `Keychain`, but it is storage purposed for sensitive data like passwords, certificates etc.

`CoreData` is basically a `SQLite` wrapper, which means that the backing `SQLite` database (file) is stored in the application sandbox.

If you referring to reinstallation of the whole iOS operating system, you can first create a backup which you can recover later and the data should be restored.

But, if you are talking about persisting data while reinstalling your app, you need to look into how to store them on remote storage (can be iCloud, Realm Cloud etc, your custom API/backend) and synchronize them to some remote storage.

I recommend you to look into [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit) (iCloud API) as it is Apple platform and possibly purposed for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data uses SQLite under the hood as a default, so your question is wrong a bit.

I will try to give you an answer, if `deleting then installing the the ios` means deleting application and installing it again. Your application runs in a sandbox, so all the data you have in your DB will be removed after uses reinstall it.

If you want to persist it:

- You must have some remote storage
- If chunk of data is small, you can store it in keychain.

Hope it helps